# Given $a^3+b^3=1$ and $(a+b)(a+1)(b+1)=2$, find the value of $(a+b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math, systems-of-equations, substitution

> Given: $(a,b)\subset \mathbb R^2$, $a^3+b^3=1$ and $(a+b)(a+1)(b+1)=2$.
>
> Find: The value of $(a+b)$

Question on the Brazilian Math Olympic (OBM), level 2, phase 3, 2012. No answer provided.

By inspection I can easily see that $(a,b)=(1,0)$, $(a,b)=(0,1)$, are possible solutions, leading to $(a+b)=1$. But are there other solutions? I developed both terms using usual identities, but I'm missing something.

Hints and solutions are appreciated. Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inherent symmetries suggest to introduce the elementary symmetric functions of $a$ and $b$ as new variables:
$$a+b=:u,\qquad ab=:v\ .$$
Then
$$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)=u(u^2-3v),\qquad(a+1)(b+1)=v+u+1\ .$$
The two given equations then amount to
$$u(u^2-3v)=1,\qquad u(v+u+1)=2\ .\tag{1}$$
In particular $u\ne0$, hence we can solve the second equation $(1)$ for $v$ and obtain
$$v={2\over u}-u-1\ .$$
Plugging this into the first equation $(1)$ we obtain
$$u\left(u^2-3\left({2\over u}-u-1\right)\right)=1\ ,$$
or
$$(u+1)^3=8\ .$$
The only real solution of this equation is $u=1$, and this is also the only possible real value of $a+b$. In order to make sure that real $a$, $b$ satisfying the original conditions indeed exist note that $u=1$ implies $v=0$, and it is then easy to check that $(a,b)\in\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$ are o.k.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Thank you. I was aware of the discrepancy, but just was not able to pinpoint the error. It should be correct now.

Answer (score 9):

Let $a+b=2u$ and $ab=v^2$.

Thus, $$2u(4u^2-3v^2)=1$$ and
$$2u(v^2+2u+1)=2.$$
From the last we obtain $$v^2=\frac{1}{u}-2u-1$$
Id est,
$$2u\left(4u^2-3\left(\frac{1}{u}-2u-1\right)\right)=1$$ or
$$(2u-1)(4u^2+8u+7)=0$$ or
$$2u=1$$ or
$$a+b=1.$$

Comment: I'm curious...how did you do this so quickly?  Is there intuition behind the substitution?

Comment: You make the change $ab=v^2.$ Is not possible to have $ab<0?$

Comment: @lulu I just like to prove inequalities, where we need a good technique.

Comment: @Lulu I think only $a+b$ and $ab$ appear in the expressions. SO better substitute them!

Comment: @mfl Yes $v^2$ can be negative.

Comment: @lulu For intuition on the substitution, we have that the polynomials in the problem are all symmetric, and it is a standard result that all symmetric polynomials are generated by the elementary symmetric polynomials (though there are other families that they are generated by as well).  It makes sense to try to write everything in terms of them.

Comment: When you say "or" does it mean union of solutions like [$x=1$ or $x=2$] or something else? Otherwise equivalences are usually denoted as $\Leftrightarrow$.

Comment: @A.Γ Here it means "it's the same". Read please better all text.

Comment: I have read all the text, that's why I ask. In mathematics, "or" does not usually mean "the same". It means "another option than mentioned"

Answer (score 3):

$(a+b)^3 = a^3+b^3+3a^2b+3ab^2$

$
2=(a+b)(a+1)(b+1)
=(a^2 b + a b^2) + (a+b)^2+ (a+b)
$

Let $u=a+b$ and $v=a^2 b + a b^2$.

Then $u^3=1+3v, 2=v+u^2+u$ and so
$u^3 + 3 u^2 + 3 u - 7=0$.

Now, $u^3 + 3 u^2 + 3 u - 7 = (u+1)^3-8$. Therefore, $u+1=2$ and $u=1$.